# list of lambdas in R

Tags: r

I want to make an R function that returns a list of functions that each operate on a different part of a list. However, because of R's rules on scope, this seems impossible. Here's an example:

```
functiontest = function() {
    foo = list()
    for(i in 1:3) {
        fixer = function(s) { return(
            function() {
                return(s)
            }
        )}
        foo[[i]] = fixer(i)
    }
    return(foo)
}

functiontest()[[2]]() #returns 3
```

Even killing off the named lambda "fixer" and using an immediate function doesn't save me:

```
functiontest = function() {
    foo = list()
    for(i in 1:3) {
        foo[[i]]=(function(s) { return(
            function() {
                return(s)
            }
        )})(i)
    }
    return(foo)
}

functiontest()[[2]]() #returns 3
```

I want this to return 2. How can I refactor this code so that this will happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the problem you have faced has nothing to do with the scoping. Second, I don't think it is a good idea to call something idiotic just because you don't understand it.

In your example, all functions in a list return the same value because of the lazy evaluation mechanism in R. See `help(force)`, which specifically addresses your question. In short, you need to force evaluation of the function at the time you call it, which can be done by adding `force`:

```
functiontest = function() {
    foo = list()
    for(i in 1:3) {
        fixer = function(s) { 
            force(s) ### <<<---This is the only difference from your code ###
            return(
            function() {
                return(s)
            }
        )}
        foo[[i]] = fixer(i)
    }
    return(foo)
}
```

or, using a more concise syntax:

```
functiontest <- function()  lapply(1:3, function(s) {s; function() s})
```

Example of use:

```
> L <- functiontest()

> L[[1]]()
[1] 1

> L[[2]]()
[1] 2

> L[[3]]()
[1] 3
```